# I am having issue with my Fuzzy PD controller simulation in Simulink "shutting off" instead of having a continuous response

Tags: matlab, controller, simulink, servo

Update: I have figured out the main issue, the error change boundaries were off. I swear I checked those, but I messed that up. Now I am struggling to get it slowed down. Despite having multiple lower voltage sets, the overshoot remains about 20%

In my project I made a fuzzy set PD controller to control the response of a servo motor, bounded by -15 and 15 Volts. I have done this previously without much issue, the response in the proportional controller was continuous. For some reason, I cannot figure out, I can't get a continuous response, and I believe that is the cause of my controller's poor response. Please let me know what I have done wrong, I have been trying many different sets and rules, and I cannot figure out this issue.

The MATLAB code Updated:

```
clear all
close all
clc

plot_flag = 1;

fisv1 = mamfis("Name","Controller");


fisv1 = addInput(fisv1,[-1.5 1.5],"Name","error");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "error", "trapmf", [-1.5 -1.5 -.8 -.7],'Name',"LN");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "error", "trapmf", [-.8 -.7 -.5 -.4],'Name',"MN");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "error", "trapmf", [-.5 -.4 -.2 0],'Name',"SN");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "error", "trimf", [-.01 0 .01],'Name',"Ze");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "error", "trapmf", [0 .2 .4 .5],'Name',"SP");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "error", "trapmf", [.4 .5 .7 .8],'Name',"MP");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "error", "trapmf", [.7 .8 1.5 1.5],'Name',"LP");

fisv1 = addInput(fisv1,[-65 65],"Name","echange");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "echange", "trapmf", [-65 -65 -8 -6],'Name',"LN");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "echange", "trapmf", [-12 -10 -6 -4],'Name',"MN");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "echange", "trapmf", [-6 -4 -2 0],'Name',"SN");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "echange", "trimf", [-.01 0 .01],'Name',"Ze");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "echange", "trapmf", [0 2 4 6],'Name',"SP");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "echange", "trapmf", [4 6 10 12],'Name',"MP");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "echange", "trapmf", [10 15 65 65],'Name',"LP");

fisv1 = addOutput(fisv1,[-14.8 14.8], 'Name',"control");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "control", "trapmf", [-14.8 -14.8 -10 -8],'Name',"XLN");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "control", "trapmf", [-9 -8 -6 -4],'Name',"LN");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "control", "trapmf", [-6 -4 -2 -1],'Name',"MN");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "control", "trapmf", [-2 -1 -.5 0],'Name',"SN");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "control", "trimf",  [-.01 0 .01],'Name',"Ze");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "control", "trapmf", [0 .5 1 2],'Name',"SP");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "control", "trapmf", [1 2 4 6],'Name',"MP");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "control", "trapmf", [4 6 8 9],'Name',"LP");
fisv1 = addMF(fisv1, "control", "trapmf", [8 10 15 15],'Name',"XLP");


% LN MN SN Ze SP MP LP
% 1  2  3  4  5  6  7
% 
% XLN LN MN SN Ze SP MP LP XLP
% 1   2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9

rulelist1 = [1 1 1 1 1;
             1 2 1 1 1;
             1 3 2 1 1;
             1 4 2 1 1;
             1 5 2 1 1;
             1 6 2 1 1;
             1 7 2 1 1;             
             2 1 2 1 1;
             2 2 2 1 1;
             2 3 3 1 1;
             2 4 3 1 1;
             2 5 3 1 1;
             2 6 3 1 1;
             2 7 3 1 1;
             3 1 3 1 1;
             3 2 3 1 1;
             3 3 4 1 1;
             3 4 4 1 1;
             3 5 4 1 1;
             3 6 4 1 1;
             3 7 4 1 1;
             4 0 5 1 1;
             5 1 6 1 1;
             5 2 6 1 1;
             5 3 6 1 1;
             5 4 6 1 1;
             5 5 6 1 1;
             5 6 7 1 1;
             5 7 7 1 1;
             6 1 7 1 1;
             6 2 7 1 1;
             6 3 7 1 1;
             6 4 7 1 1;
             6 5 7 1 1;
             6 6 8 1 1;
             6 7 8 1 1;
             7 1 8 1 1;
             7 2 8 1 1;
             7 3 8 1 1;
             7 4 8 1 1;
             7 5 8 1 1;
             7 6 9 1 1;
             7 7 9 1 1;
             ];


fisv1 = addRule(fisv1,rulelist1);

getfis(fisv1)

disp('showrule(fisv1)')
showrule(fisv1)
% disp('showrule(fis1,[1:7],"indexed")')
% showrule(fis1,[1:7],"indexed")
% disp('showrule(fis1,[1 2 3 4 5 6 7],"symbolic")')
% showrule(fis1,[1 2 3 4 5 6 7],'symbolic')

if plot_flag == 1
    figure()
    plotfis(fisv1);
    figure;
    gensurf(fisv1);
end
```

The Simulink setup:
[Simulink PD controller](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JnUFN.png)

[Fuzzy PD Controller Output][(https://i.stack.imgur.com/c60hP.png)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KbM8k.png)

Resulting Response of the system

I have tried to keep this as simple as possible to find the issue in this response. I am trying for a continuous response that controls this system within about 30 to 40ms. Thank you for any help with this!

I have tried changing sets, rules, and set types. This should control the servo continuously, but it does not. I have also asked for help, but no one I know has seen this type of issue before. The step size is set in Simulink to be 1/1000, and should be more than enough to show a continuous, not jagged, response.